# How to make a responsive scrollable div inside another div using pure CSS

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow, scrollable

My webpage looks like this[image]

My aim is to make the Outer Pad's height to fit the viewport height and make the inner Checklist scrollable. I have tried

```
.html{
    height: 100%;
}  

.pad{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.list{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chandannadig/esmrLzuv/10/

The moment scrollbars are visible, the data is pushed towards left and the pseudo elements I have used to get the folded effect are screwed up. I want to achieve the following:

1. Make '.list' scrollable without showing scrollbars
2. The pseudo elements should not be affected by the scrollbars
3. The design should be responsive

Please help me achieve this

Comment: Please update your question to include enough of the relevant HTML & CSS to replicate the problem.

Comment: I've added link to the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle(The html is not looking similar to the screenshot given above however i tried my best to provide you a solution).

I have added

```
.content {
  overflow: scroll;
  width: calc(100% + 20px);
  height:100%;
}
```

It solve the purpose list is scrollable calc(100% + 20px) adds extra space for scrollbar and it is responsive as well.